# Issue with Prime React Infinite scroll lazy with loading

Tags: datatable, infinite-scroll, primereact, virtualscroll, react-scroll

I'm currently working with a large dataset and have implemented virtual scrolling along with lazy loading to improve performance.

However, I'm encountering a few issues that I'd like assistance with when posting my questions on Stack Overflow:

Optimizing Network Calls: The current implementation fetches around 40 records per request, but after reaching 13 records, it triggers another set of 40 requests. I'm looking for ways to optimize this process and reduce unnecessary network calls. Unfortunately, I couldn't find sufficient resources online to address this issue.

Skeleton Alignment Issue: The skeleton loading animation doesn't align correctly, covering only half of the table. I'm seeking guidance on how to fix this alignment problem.

Smoothing the User Experience: I'm also interested in improving the overall smoothness of the virtual scrolling and lazy loading implementation. Any insights or tips on enhancing the user experience would be greatly appreciated.

I plan to post these questions on Stack Overflow to gather insights from the community. If you have expertise in any of these areas, your input would be invaluable.

[Github code](https://github.com/Vasukommi/react-virtual-grid-r-and-d/blob/main/src/components/prime-react/PrimeTable.tsx)

[Recorder video](https://www.loom.com/share/be185f3dd1fe469bb42c865083f85712?sid=eb93e3ae-1db2-4bc6-b647-88c9160846c6)

I want to make it smooth and optimal trying findout ways to do it.